# How to make vba function which contain a double select

Tags: sql, vba, function, counter

I used to have a sub for this proccess, but Im trying to convert into a function without success. Is it possible? If a try to do a sub routine it work perfectly. Maybe it is only about the difference between a Sub and a function but I´m not sure of this. I was looking on the internet for hours but i dint find answers. Could you please help me? Thank you in advanced

```
Function Comparacion_Ventas(Pais As String, _
                            Tienda_Anterior As Integer, _ 
                            Tienda_Posterior As Integer, _ 
                            AñoEstudio As Integer, _
                            MesEstudio As Integer, _ 
                            AñoPosteriorEstudio As Integer, _ 
                            AñoAnteriorComparado As Integer)

    Dim Posterior As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim Anterior  As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim sql As String
    Dim carac_conn As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    Dim Diferencia_Ventas As Double
    Dim Diferencia_Alquileres As Double
    Dim Suma_Ventas As Double
    Dim Suma_Alquileres As Double

    Diferencia_Ventas = 0
    Diferencia_Alquileres = 0
    Suma_Ventas = 0
    Suma_Alquileres = 0

    sql = "SELECT EBIT_Nuevo_" & Pais & ".Tienda, EBIT_Nuevo_" & Pais & ".Ejercicio, EBIT_Nuevo_" & Pais & ".Periodo_Contable, EBIT_Nuevo_" & Pais & _ 
          ".Cifra_de_Ventas, EBIT_Nuevo_" & Pais & ".ALQUILERES" & _
          " FROM EBIT_Nuevo_" & Pais & "" & _
          " WHERE ((EBIT_Nuevo_" & Pais & ".Tienda IN (" & Tienda_Posterior & ") ) AND ((EBIT_Nuevo_" & Pais & ".Cifra_de_Ventas > 0)) AND " & _
          "((EBIT_Nuevo_" & Pais & ".Ejercicio=" & AñoEstudio & ") AND (EBIT_Nuevo_" & Pais & ".Periodo_Contable>" & MesEstudio & ") OR " & _
          "(EBIT_Nuevo_" & Pais & ".Ejercicio=" & AñoPosteriorEstudio & ") AND (EBIT_Nuevo_" & Pais & ".Periodo_Contable<=" & MesEstudio & "))) " & _
          " ORDER BY EBIT_Nuevo_" & Pais & ".Tienda, EBIT_Nuevo_" & Pais & ".Ejercicio, EBIT_Nuevo_" & Pais & ".Periodo_Contable "

    carac_conn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Basetdas_New.mdb"
    ' Conexión a BD
    conn.Open ConnectionString:=carac_conn
    ' Petición a BD
    Posterior.Open Source:=sql, ActiveConnection:=conn

    ' Datos obtenidos
    If Posterior.EOF = True Then
        MsgBox " No hay datos en la base de datos", vbInformation
    Else
        Posterior_array = Posterior.GetRows()
    End If

    Posterior.Close
    conn.Close

    sql = "SELECT EBIT_Nuevo_" & Pais & ".Tienda, EBIT_Nuevo_" & Pais & ".Ejercicio, EBIT_Nuevo_" & Pais & ".Periodo_Contable, EBIT_Nuevo_" & _ 
          Pais & ".Cifra_de_Ventas, EBIT_Nuevo_" & Pais & ".ALQUILERES" & _
          " FROM EBIT_Nuevo_" & Pais & "" & _
          " WHERE ((EBIT_Nuevo_" & Pais & ".Tienda IN (" & Tienda_Anterior & ") ) AND ((EBIT_Nuevo_" & Pais & ".Cifra_de_Ventas > 0)) AND " & _
          "((EBIT_Nuevo_" & Pais & ".Ejercicio=2013) AND (EBIT_Nuevo_" & Pais & ".Periodo_Contable<" & MesEstudio & ") OR " & _
          "(EBIT_Nuevo_" & Pais & ".Ejercicio=" & AñoAnteriorComparado & ") AND (EBIT_Nuevo_" & Pais & ".Periodo_Contable>=" & MesEstudio & "))) " & _
          " ORDER BY EBIT_Nuevo_" & Pais & ".Tienda, EBIT_Nuevo_" & Pais & ".Ejercicio, EBIT_Nuevo_" & Pais & ".Periodo_Contable "

    carac_conn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Basetdas_New.mdb"
    ' Conexión a BD
    conn.Open ConnectionString:=carac_conn
    ' Petición a BD
    Anterior.Open Source:=sql, ActiveConnection:=conn

    ' Datos obtenidos
    If Anterior.EOF = True Then
        MsgBox " No hay datos en la base de datos", vbInformation
    Else
        Anterior_array = Anterior.GetRows()
    End If

    Anterior.Close
    conn.Close

    For i = 0 To UBound(Anterior_array, 2)
        For j = 0 To UBound(Posterior_array, 2)
            If Posterior_array(2, j) = Anterior_array(2, i) Then
                Diferencia_Ventas = 0
                Diferencia_Ventas = Posterior_array(3, j) - Anterior_array(3, i)
                Sheets("Example").Cells(i, 2) = Diferencia_Ventas
                Suma_Ventas = Suma_Ventas + Diferencia_Ventas
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    Comparacion_Ventas = Suma_Ventas
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't declared a variable type to be returned by the function. The sequence goes like so:

```
Function SomeName(Parameters) AS Double

    'Do something'

    SomeName = SomeVariable

End Function
```

Notice the `AS Double` which will return the value you've assigned to the function.

Remeber to change `Double` to the actual data type that you're trying to return.

Comment: Thank you Gareth, I´ve change the code as you mentioned and Im still getting a #VALUE! error in excel.  My actual data type is double.

Comment: Could you try executing the function in the VBA editor and let us know if an error occurs please?

Comment: The function works right in vba. So I guess Im doing something wrong in the excel sheet.

Comment: Try going to the Formulas tab -> Evaluate Formula as this this may shed some light on where it's failing.

Comment: It is a #VALUE! error, Could be something related to data type? It makes no sense for me. Im calling the function from the sheet in the same way as I did in VBA.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to tell without more detail. What are you trying to return from the function?

Comment: I think the best data type for this function is single because the return is a number between 12039.43 and 5263141.21. I've tried with other types and it always return the same error in de sheet. Please could you tell me what information can help you in order to solve my problem? The code is working so I´m going to click the check of problem solved.

Comment: It is solved! =) This was written in the code: "Sheets("Example").Cells(i, 2) = Diferencia_Ventas"  It was something for me to text the code but i dindt realise that i was breaking the function when is called from one sheet.  Thank you for your help!!!